# How to include all css kept in a directory?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to include multiple css at once in html? Or to be precise, is it possible to include all css placed in a directory, in one go?
like at present what we do is:-

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./tabs_css/navigation.css">
```

I need something like:-

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./tabs_css/*.css">
```

Is it possible? Or is there any alternative of this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could create a master stylesheet that you include in every page, and within that css file you can use `@import` to include the others.

This doesn't solve the problem of having to manually include each individual css file, but at least it encapsulates it within the master stylesheet so you don't have to repeat all of the references in every html file.  If you add additional css files you will only need to add a reference in the master css and all pages will get access to it.

Example HTML CSS Reference:

```html
<link href="master.css" type="text/css" />
```

Example Master CSS (`master.css`):

```css
@import url(style1.css);
@import url(style2.css);
@import url(style3.css);
```

Read more about [when to use @import and its compatibility with older browsers](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/f/css_import_link.htm).

Comment: I'm glad the solution works for you, but there are some good points to be made in the other answers and comments as well.  If at all possible you should consider combining the css files into one.

Answer (score 9):

You'd need to do this serverside. If you're using PHP, have a look at [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

For example:

```
foreach (glob("path/to/css/*.css") as $css) {
    echo "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='$css'>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible to use wildcards in a href. You will need to specify a link tag for every css file you need to include.

Comment: you mean if there are 20 css in directory, then i will have to mention all 20 css!!

Comment: You should consider combining some of these css files together. Or if you do keep all twenty, make sure that caching is working correctly.

Comment: 20 CSS files is a little excessive.

Comment: @skilldrick: please define `excessive`

Comment: If you find you need to include 20 CSS files, there's probably a better way of doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaken, this can be done quite nicely (though still manually) similar to JavaScript.

```
./styles/
   ./layouts/
      all.css      <-- Each subfolder has this
      header.css
      footer.css
      nav.css
   ./main.css      <-- Main CSS file
```

Inside `./styles/layouts/all.css` do you import:

```
@import 'layouts/header.css';
@import 'layouts/footer.css';
@import 'layouts/nav.css';
```

Right, this separates the minor logic in CSS organizatoin (which is good IMHO).

Then, as many "all.css" files in subfolders there are, just include them (Example):

**main.css**

```
@import 'variables/all.css';
@import 'layouts/all.css';
```

I think thats rather nice...

Answer (score 0):

You could write a server-side script that concatenate all of the files in the directory and sends that to the client, then put the script in a `<link>` tag.

However, beware of syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do it client side. It is possible to do it with the help of a server side technology. But, the best approach would be to incorporate all CSS into a single file and include that.
If you still want to keep css splited to files, do what many do and use a build tool thay incorporate all css into one file just for the production/testing server

Answer (score 0):

you could use php to list all file with css extension in that directory...

```
$fp = opendir($dir);
while ($file = readdir($fp)) {
        if (strpos($file, '.css',1))
            $results[] = $file;
    }
closedir($fp);
```

...and than do a foreach construct to incude css's

Comment: From his other questions, it looks like he uses Java.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm about 12 years late on this one, but figured I'd throw out an idea for anyone still coming across this:

I've started using a `classes.php` file as such:

```
class Structure {
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->head = '
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/styles/filename1.css'/>
            <!-- Add additional .css files here -->
            ';
    }
}
```

Then in my `.php` pages (all of them), I do the following:

```
<?php
require 'classes.php';
$str = new Structure();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php echo $str->head; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Normal Body Stuff Here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

This way, I only need to update 1 file to update all the other pages.

As a side note, I also add `<footer>`, any recurring `<nav>`, or anything else I don't want to have to copy/paste over and over. I only access the parts I want with `echo $str->key;`

Answer (score -1):

There may be some possible workarounds:

- Consider the idea of importing a PHP page (e.g. ./tabs_css/allcss.php) which concatenates and returns all the css in the directory. This may be a little CPU intensive.
- Consider creating a combo css file which is concatenation of all of your CSS files. This might be possible to create automatically by adding special hooks to your version-control system.