# HTML Resource Preloading - Possible to use Wildcard?

Tags: html, wildcard, preload

I am using `<link rel="preload" href="/my/resources/..." as="..." />` to preload resources. I am wondering if it's possible to preload everything under a specific path without manually enumerating them?

Something like `<link rel="preload" href="/my/css/*.css" as="style" />` (this one I already tried, `*` gets parsed literally and gives 404, but you get the idea).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include all css kept in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326502/how-to-include-all-css-kept-in-a-directory)

Comment: @AhmedAli Unfortunately, no. I am asking about preloading. The solution you linked 1. is CSS specific, not generalisable; 2. does not preload anything; 3. still requires manual enumeration.

Comment: it can only be done using server side language