# Can I do regular expression in html to match css & js?

Tags: html, css, glob

As one is quite familiar with shell, and using regular expressions to match (?dunno if so called) files just like `'*.jpg'` or stuff is fine in python, therefore, one is just wondering whether it is ok for one to link css/js files the way below:

`<link href = './*.css' rel = 'stylesheet'>`

Sorry if this is a really stupid question: I am bloody hell noob...

Comment: I'm afraid no, you can't. But you can do something like this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326502/how-to-include-all-css-kept-in-a-directory

Comment: As far as I'm aware, HTML only supports regex in `pattern` of the input tag.