# how to include all css file inside folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a few files inside a folder or public folder. I don't know how many files there are in the folder. I want to include all `.css` files that start with `main`.

Here is my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-tdd-cgcrz?file=/public/test.css

For example I have three files in my folder `main.css` ,`main1.css` and `test.css`. I only want `main.css` and `main1.css` to be included and not `test.css`;
I tried like this

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <link href="main*.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </Head>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link href="/about">
        <a className="red">About</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you can use a css preprocessor like SCSS (Sass) for that

Comment: no. these files are created from an API or downloaded from API .

Comment: Can you get a list of all the files you need to load? not sure you can wildcard it as servers dont usually allow listing all files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include all css kept in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326502/how-to-include-all-css-kept-in-a-directory)

Comment: from api response it download few files.i want to include those file which start from main

Comment: no. here you know there are 3 files in a folder with there names .but in my example i don't know how many files are there